# Update de multiples filas con distintos valores

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando actualizar distintas filas con distintos valores, en mi tabla sql, lo mas cerca que he llegado es:

```
UPDATE cursos    
SET posicion = 11
where Id in (1,2)
```

Pero me actualiza con el mismo valor (11) logicamente las dos filas, yo necesito darle un valor distinto a cada fila. Alguien me podria ayudar con este dilema je?. Gracias!!!

Comment: Pues tan sencillo como hacer un Update distonto por cada fila. ¿Donde ves el problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un condicional, como CASE ... END, el cual va a asignar un valor a posicion según el id:

```
UPDATE cursos    
SET posicion = CASE Id
    WHEN 1 THEN 11
    WHEN 2 THEN 15
END
WHERE Id IN (1,2)
```

De esta forma, el curso con id=1 tendrá posicion=11 y el curso con id=2 tendrá posicion=15.